# proxy configuration for spring ROO

Tags: configuration, proxy, java, spring-roo

I can not configure the proxy to download the dependencies:
Initially when I tried to build the project. received the message timeout. Now gotta find a configuration file that solved my problem in parts.
the file is net.properties which is inside the directory of the jdk, it is where I can specify the proxy server but can not get past the User and password for authentication.

any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the following additional parameters in your `net.properties` file.

```
http.proxyUser=xxxxx
http.proxyPassword=xxxxx
```

Else, you can setup a local proxy server (with no authentication) which supports authentication to the proxy server you are using and point your `net.properties` to it.

Cheers.